# Rendering a scene created in Blender with Babylon.js without the Babylon.js default shiny material

Tags: javascript, 3d, rendering, blender, babylonjs

I've a really simple scene created in Blender with a plane, a cube, a sun (AKA directional light) and a camera:
[image: Blender scene]

Rendered, it's looking like this:
[image: Blender's scene rendered]

My problem is, when I export this scene to .babylon file format, and load it into Babylon, it does not look like this at all. It seems that Babylon sets a specular-shiny-weirdy material to all my meshes:
[image: Babylon's scene rendered]

I'd like to have a "matte" (I mean, opaque and rough) material, like in Blender's render, in my Babylon scene as well, or at least suppress the specular thing, to make the meshes look like rough.
Unfortunately I didn't encounter any case like mine on the internet yet.

Some informations about what I'm using:

- Blender 2.74
- Blender to Babylon exporter (downloaded two days ago, I think it's the latest, still I can't figure out what version it is)
- Babylon.js v2.1
- Google Chrome for MacOSX

I'm working on a python localhost server, so I can't provide a working example, but at least [here's my .babylon scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ak3oiub6113eigf/Cube_and_plane.babylon?dl=0) and my html code:

```js
<script>
    if (BABYLON.Engine.isSupported()) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
        var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "Cube_and_plane.babylon", engine, function (newScene) {
            // Wait for textures and shaders to be ready
            newScene.executeWhenReady(function () {
                // Attach camera to canvas inputs
                newScene.activeCamera.attachControl(canvas);

                // Add shadows
                var shadowGenerator = new BABYLON.ShadowGenerator(2048, newScene.lights[0]);
                for (var i = 0; i < newScene.meshes.length; ++i) {
                    shadowGenerator.getShadowMap().renderList.push(newScene.meshes[i]);
                    newScene.meshes[i].receiveShadows = true;
                };

                // Once the scene is loaded, just register a render loop to render it
                engine.runRenderLoop(function() {
                    newScene.render();
                });
            });
        }, function (progress) {
            // To do: give progress feedback to user
        });
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Hello just set your specular color to black.

Answer (score 0):

The question might still be relevant to someone..

If you use the Babylon Blender Exporter 4.6.1 then the settings don't show up on the "Export page" (on the left side) as is the case for other exporters, but shows up under "Scene" (on the right side):

[image]

You want to check "Flat shade entire scene" otherwise smooth shading is used.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not work on this anymore, thus I'm not able to test it. But thanks for your answer :D.

Answer (score 0):

If you want load blender tool scene in babylonJS framework. follow this link (https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#QWIJYE#24). This project needs to return at least an empty scene and default blender camera and lights.